# Cant make bibliography with cyrillic: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: bibtex, texshop, input-encodings, bibdesk, installing-fonts

I have some error, trying to manage my references.

I am using Mac with Texshop and BibDesk. They both work absolutely fine in english, but when i try something with russian word in .bib file gives that error

```
./error_example.bbl:25: Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.25 Ð.
       ~Ð®.Ð., \emph{ÐÑÐ±ÐžÑÐµÑÐºÐžÐµ ÑÐŸÑÐŒÑ}.\hskip 1em plus 0.5em...

?
```

My .bib file looks like that:

```
%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 

@book{cubic_forms,
    author = {Манин Ю.И.},
    date-added = {2023-11-14 17:13:52 +0300},
    date-modified = {2023-11-14 17:42:26 +0300},
    publisher = {Наука},
    title = {Кубические формы},
    year = {1972.}}
```

BibDesk saves in UTF-8 format and my code looks like that

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

This is from \cite{cubic_forms}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ref.bib}

\end{document}
```

How can i fix this? Is that a Texshop problem?

UPD: As i can see, i can ignore all that warnings and compile that. Also i figured out, that if i change `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` to `\bibliographystyle{plain}` or different styles, it works. IEEEtran was very good style for my because of it's links visualization. Can i fix it without switching to biblatex/biber and changing my programs? Ideally, i would like to keep IEEEtran as bibliographystyle.

UPD2: I discovered, that problem is starting, when IEEEtran translates `.bib` file to `.bbl`. Can i add something to make it better?

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full bit minimal example that others can copy and test as is. In general I would not expect `bibtex` to handle UTF8 code correctly. You might want to have a look at `biblatex` which the `biber` backend.

Comment: Given that bibtex sorts on author, a russian name in utf8 will probably not work as bibtex has no idea on how to sort it.

Comment: Note that the code works well using `biblatex` and `biber` though I don't know which style is equivalent to `IEEEtran`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `biblatex` with the `ieee` style.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{cubic_forms,
    author = {Манин, Ю. И.},
    date-added = {2023-11-14 17:13:52 +0300},
    date-modified = {2023-11-14 17:42:26 +0300},
    publisher = {Наука},
    title = {Кубические формы},
    year = {1972.},
    langid={russian},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}  
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,autolang=other*]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is from \cite{cubic_forms}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents*` just to make the example self-contained. Replace `\jobname.bib` in `\addbibresource` with the actual name of your bib file.

However, note the fixes in the bib entry: a comma was missing and also a space between the initials.

Run `pdflatex`, then `biber` and then `pdflatex` again.

[image]